# Не корректно отображается окружность UIView

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

При закруглении вьюшки, на симуляторе и девайсе видны дефекты в окружности, очень отвратительно выглядит. Есть еще какие-нибудь варианты реализовать идеально красивый круг, без искажений и дефектов? Спасибо

```
circleView.layer.cornerRadius = 0.5 * circleView.bounds.size.width
circleView.clipsToBounds = true
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите помогут ли следующие опции (спойлер: вряд ли). Кроме того, у вас тут судя по всему граница тоньше 1, в этом случае такие эффекты пилообразной границы усугубляются, и чем меньше разрешение экрана на устройстве, тем хуже будет выглядеть. Решение - либо совсем убрать границу, либо попробовать использовать тень с минимальным размытием под вьюшкой, ну или как советуют также здесь, изображение, хотя при использовании растеризации мы по сути получаем тот же эффект.

```
circleView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
circleView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale;
circleView.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
```

Comment: Попробовал предыдущие советы и ваш, но ничего не помогло

Comment: @ArturSkachkov попробуйте сделать с тенью

Comment: Пошел обратным путем))) Наоборот добавил рамку для вьюхи, сделал не сильно толстой. Она и закрыла эти края вьюхи корректно, даже на анимации здорово работает. Единственное из-за градиента вьюхи пришлось подобрать приблизительный цвет для рамки, нечто средний, не много заметна она на фоне кругов, но в целом сойдет. Спасибо за советы))

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать реальное изображение круга в виде image, а не нарисованное программно. Также, если у Вас circleView.layer.borderWidth отлично от 0, попробуйте установить в 0.

Comment: Убрал рамку, попробовал использовать image - не помогло, аналогичное отображение